# How to make any instance creation a fake (FakeItEasy)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I have this block of code that I would like to test

```
class SearchEngine
{
    public void Search()
    {
        var module = new SearchModule();
        module.Search();
    }
}
```

I have simplified it but I cannot provide a searchmodule instance as a parameter of the function `Search`, nor as a constructor parameter of the class `SearchEngine`.

**Is there a way to insure that the `module` object will be a fakeiteasy fake when I write my unit test?**

I would like to be able to do some `CallTo` verifications to the module object, notably that `module.Search()` was called when we call `Search()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to insure that the module object will be a fakeiteasy fake when I write my unit test?

No, it's not possible, at least not with the current shape of your code. FakeItEasy can't intercept instance creation using `new`.

If you want to fake something, it has to be provided somehow to the system under test. The SUT can't create it itself.

> I cannot provide a searchmodule instance as a parameter of the function `Search`, nor as a constructor parameter of the class `SearchEngine`

Could you inject a factory instead? Something like this:

```cs
public interface ISearchModuleFactory
{
    SearchModule Create();
}


class SearchEngine
{
    private readonly ISearchModuleFactory _searchModuleFactory;

    public SearchEngine(ISearchModuleFactory searchModuleFactory)
    {
        _searchModuleFactory = searchModuleFactory;
    }

    public void Search()
    {
        var module = _searchModuleFactory.Create();
        module.Search();
    }
}
```

You could then test SearchEngine like this:

```cs
// Arrange
var factory = A.Fake<ISearchModuleFactory>();
var module = A.Fake<SearchModule>();
A.CallTo(() => factory.Create()).Returns(module);
var searchEngine = new SearchEngine(factory);

// Act
searchEngine.Search();

// Assert
A.CallTo(() => module.Search()).MustHaveHappened();
```

Comment: I like this approach, it'll also help scale for future modules that could be added.

Thanks for suggesting something slightly outside of my question, I'm a bit rusty and this is exactly what I needed !